# Is drinking 'radioactive carbon-14' safe?

Tags: toxicity, radioactivity, drinks, urea, breathalyzer

How safe is drinking radioactive carbon-14 during urea breath test?

Comment: It's safe because all such tests have been designed while taking into account rigorous safety standards. The assumptions made about the dangers of radiation in these safety standards is that exposure to small amounts of radiation can be harmful to the point that it's actually not all that credible. So, it's so safe that even if the C-14 would have been replaced by an isotope that's a thousand times more radioactive, it would still be harmless.

Comment: Also, take a note of this: http://www.bbc.co.uk/pressoffice/pressreleases/stories/2006/07_july/11/horizon.shtml "
What is accepted by all the experts Horizon talked to is that for the victims of Chernobyl the real problem is not radiation - but radiophobia, the fear of radiation, which has caused acute psychological trauma."

Comment: @CountIblis It's a shame you answered in comments instead of writing a real answer.